# Create does not work in GAE Datastore viewer

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When I try to create some entities I don't see the option to input fields. I just see the SaveEntity button.

[image]

However I can view all the existing entities.

[image]

What is very strange is - there is another entity called VideoEntity for which the create did not work yesterday but works today.

Can somebody help me with this seemingly unpredictable tool ?

Regards,
Sathya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the console knows what properties each entity has based on existing data, rather then your models. and the data is only updated periodically. when did you upload your app? maybe waiting a few hours will give the console time to update.

alternatively, you could use the remote api to add your entities, or write a small snippet and upload such as ...

```
VideoStatsEntity(app='home', ip='116.89.52.67', params='tag=20130210').put()
```

Comment: Thanks Gwyn and Paul. I am new to datastore but I think it should be a pretty fundamental requirement for every developer to be able to insert/delete/update entities without building a custom UI for every entity. Is it such a big deal for Google to provide a nice web UI (enhancement to existing datastore viewer ?) that supports all CRUD operations in a simple and intuitive way ? Just a web wrapper to remote api should do the job. I am curious as to why Google is not providing this. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: I guess the biggest thing your missing is how easy it is to write your own! It's literally a one liner to create an entity. The App Engine datastore management console is a bit old now, and they haven't updated it for some time. My guess is that an update is in the works. But also, as Paul mentioned, some property types cannot be added via a simple web form, so always better to write your own. Writing your own also allows you to easily restore default data should you need to.

Comment: Thanks Gwyn, I used RemoteApi and it works for me. I find RemoteApi a useful way to play around and understand the workings of the datastore.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a simple interface to the data-store to allow you to edit/create models is probably the best thing to do in this case. You know what they contain so you can adjust your interface accordingly, rather then waiting for the admin interface to "catch up" as Gwyn notes.

I believe that there are some property types that are impossible to add via the admin interface that you are using so you'll probably get to the point sooner rather then later of creating a custom interface.

The admin datastore view is good for quickly checking out the contents of the datastore, but ever tried paging through 100's of entries? Not fun.